# How to get both loss and model output at once, on a batch of data in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, keras

I'm using Keras w/ Tensorflow backend to train a NN.

I'm using `train_on_batch` for training, which returns the loss on the given batch. How do I also get the output classification on that batch ? (I'd like to do some visualisations of the output)

To do that I currently do another call to `predict` to get the model output, but that's redundant since train_on_batch have already passed the input batch "forward".

In Caffe, when an image is fed forward, the intermediate layer outputs stay stored in net.blobs, but in Keras/Tensorflow it seems that if we want to get an intermediate output we have to rerun the computational graph for each intermediate output we want to access on CPU, as described [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-visualize-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer). Is there a way to access many/all intermediate layers' outputs without rerunning the graph for each ?

I don't mind having a tensorflow-specific workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function API, this is pretty [straight forward](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-visualize-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer).

Comment: This returns the an intermediate output, but does not return the loss and does not update the weights.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @MohamedEzz's answer, you can create a custom callback which can perform the operations you require during the training process. They have methods which will run your code onEpochEnd, onEpochStart, onTrainingEnd and so on...
This way you can preserve the batch.